# "CUDA culnit: Unknown error" - Win8.1 - GTX780

Tags: error

Many posts but all solved same way on Windows, they downloaded and install the latest drivers, reboot and it works.
Ive heard can reinstall Blender, Or they had on Linux and was a way to recompile.

Im on Win 8.1 & reinstalled & downloaded latest Nvidia Drivers.
Ive also NOT installed Blender and have it in just a folder. 
I didnt compile and downloaded 2.80 from main website.
So "reinstalling" Blender seems non relevant

**-Should I need to download the CUDA Toolkit?**

I dont believe this issue is down to Blender, but asking here out of despiration.
Originaly was trying to get Meshroom to work but throws up following

```
Feature Extraction > Log
[20:42:21.221154][warning] Could not determine number of CUDA cards in this system[20:42:21.196294][warning] No CUDA-Enabled GPU.

[20:42:21.221154][error] cudaGetDeviceCount failed: unknown error
[20:42:21.221154][info] Can't find CUDA-Enabled GPU.
[20:42:21.771415][info] Extracting sift features from view 'F:/PG-Wall/20191117_150423.jpg' [cpu]

DepthMap > Log
[20:45:26.965401][warning] Could not determine number of CUDA cards in this system[20:45:26.940601][warning] No CUDA-Enabled GPU.

[20:45:26.965401][info] Can't find CUDA-Enabled GPU.
[20:45:26.965401][error] This program needs a CUDA-Enabled GPU (with at least compute capablility 2.0).
```

FAILS

------------------------ Not the only program not using GPU - **Adobe**

[image: after effects issue]
Adobe Premier / After Effects dont have support either - maybe why was slow rendering out video

- Adobe Premier > Project > Project Settings > General > Video Rendering and Playback > Renderer > NO HARDWARE OPTION
- Adobe AfterEffects > Edit > Preferances > Previews > GPU info > Ra-tracing > NO HARDWARE/GPU OPTION
  but ironicaly, shows under OpenGL the full GPU info/device/driver ver/RAM
  Solution is supposed to be, C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Premiere Pro CS6\cuda_supported_cards.txt -  put in gfxcard name, but doesnt work
  For AfterEffects, C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CS6\Support Files\raytracer_supported_cards.txt
  Neither works

Went into C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\OpenCL
 - OpenCL.dll & OpenCL64.dll are date 20/1/17 ?!
 - file ver 2.0.4.0 - khronos OpenCL ICD
Have heard going into RegEdit and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Khronos\OpenCL\Vendors > set Reg_DWORD to 1, but i dont have that key.

community.adobe.com/15/video-hardware/premiere-pro-using-intergrated-and-not-dedicated-graphics-card/m-p/9522355#m9155

------------------------ Not the only program not using GPU - **Blender 2.80**

Blender > Edit  > Preferances > System > Cycles Render Devices

- CUDA - "No compatible GPUs found for path tracing -  Cycles will render on the CPU"
- OpenCL - "No compatible GPUs found for path tracing -  Cycles will render on the CPU"
- Console - "CUDA culnit: Unknown error"
  [image: blender issue]

```
version: 2.80 (sub 75), branch: master, commit date: 2019-07-29 14:47, hash: f6cb5f54494e
CPU device capabilities: SSE2 SSE3 SSE41 AVX

OpenCL device capabilities:
Number of platforms: 1
Platform #0
    Platform Name: NVIDIA CUDA
    Platform Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
    Platform Version: OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 10.2.95
    Platform Profile: FULL_PROFILE
    Platform Extensions: cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics 

cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options 

cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_d3d9_sharing cl_nv_d3d10_sharing cl_khr_d3d10_sharing cl_nv_d3d11_sharing 

cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics
    Number of devices: 1
        Device: #0
            Device Name: GeForce GTX 780
            Device Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
            Device OpenCL C Version: OpenCL C 1.2 
            Device Profile: FULL_PROFILE
            Device Version: OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
            Device Extensions: cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics 

cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd 

cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_d3d9_sharing cl_nv_d3d10_sharing 

cl_khr_d3d10_sharing cl_nv_d3d11_sharing cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer cl_khr_int64_base_atomics 

cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics
            Device Max clock frequency (MHz): 954
            Device Max compute units: 12
            Device Max work group size: 1024

CUDA device capabilities:
Error initializing CUDA: Unknown error
```

------------------------ **MeshRoom** compatibilty

MeshRoom needs - Nvidia CUDA enabled GPU with CUDA compute Capability 2.0

I HAVE = Geforce GTX 780 =  **2304** CUDA Cores - CUDA compute Capability **3.5** - 3GB GDDR5 RAM - OpenGL 4.3
nvcc_ARCH += - gencode=arch=compute_35,code="sm_35,compute_35"

http://github.com/tpruvot/ccminer/wiki/Compatibility

http://geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-780/specifications

**Solutions said to Reinstall Drivers**

Downloaded Nvidia drivers: nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
Downloaded Meshroom: alicevision.org/#meshroom

Saw this video where they give you a dll file in a google drive,... as can imagine didnt feel was a good idea.
But I searched for the file name on my PC, and stuck it in the same folders

http://Youtube.com/watch?v=g5UaOIqqFX0 - Gives download - cuda_enc_windows7_8-64bit.zip
Contails nvcuvenc.dll > Paste >  C://windows/system32/ & C://windows/syswow64/

Also found following dll in same directory so tried pasting them all in Windows folders
- I pasted nvcuvenc64.dll (20/5/2014 2.66mb ver 8.17.13.3788) from C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_919a3aaa1448b25a
to C:\Windows\SysWOW64
- I pasted nvcuda64.dll (8/11/19 16.6mb ver 26.21.14.4120) from C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_f24de40315dbef04
to C:\Windows\SysWOW64
- I pasted nvcuvenc64.dll (20/5/2014 2.66mb ver 8.17.13.3788) from C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_919a3aaa1448b25a
to C:\Windows\System

- Reinstalled drivers - 436.15 - No effect
- Installed new drivers -  441.20 - No effect
- Also set task infinity to HIGH
- Set Nvidia control pannel:

  - "Power management mode - Prefer maximum performance"
  - "OpenGL rendering GPU - GeForce GTX 780"
  - "CUDA - GPUs - Use these GPUs - GeForce GTX 780"
- Doesnt matter if set "CUDA - GPUs" to "Global - All" or individually select the "Use these GPUs - GeForce GTX 780", always says "All"

```
Dxdiag > 26.21.14.3615 - 26/08/19 - Driver Model: WDDM 1.3
- NVIDIA Control Panel > System Info > Display > CUDA Cores = 2304
- NVIDIA Control Panel > System Info > Components > NVCUDA.dll = 26.21.14.3615 - NVIDIA CUDA 10.1.0 driver
Dxdiag > 26.21.14.4120 - 8/11/19 - Driver Model: WDDM 1.3
- NVIDIA Control Panel > System Info > Components > NVCUDA.dll = 26.21.14.4120 - NVIDIA CUDA 10.2.95 driver
```

```
C:\Windows\System32>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\nvidia-smi.exe"
Tue Nov 19 18:25:33 2019
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 436.15       Driver Version: 436.15       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 780    WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 48%   31C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    219MiB /  3072MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- Reinstalled drivers - 436.15 - No effect
- Installed new drivers -  441.20 - No Effect

```
C:\Windows\System32>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\nvidia-smi.exe"
Wed Nov 20 11:16:12 2019
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 441.20       Driver Version: 441.20       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 780    WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 49%   45C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    341MiB /  3072MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Unsure why no WDDM listed when DxDiag shows 1.3 which is correct and latest for Win8.1
For 2.0+ need to be on Win10
[image: nvidiaCtrl1]
[image: nvidiaCtrl2]